# ASP menu not vertical orientation not working vb.net

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

I have a asp.menu with vertical orientation. But it is not binding vertically. Please refer below image.

[image]

Please refer my code below

```
<div id="myDIV" style="padding-left:15px">
                <asp:Menu ID="mnuDynamic" runat="server" Font-Size="1.2em" StaticMenuStyle-VerticalPadding="3px" DynamicHoverStyle-BackColor="#33cc33" DynamicMenuItemStyle-HorizontalPadding="5px" 
                    StaticHoverStyle-ForeColor="YellowGreen" DynamicMenuStyle-VerticalPadding="3px" StaticMenuItemStyle-ForeColor="#cccccc" DynamicMenuItemStyle-ForeColor="#cccccc"
                    DynamicMenuStyle-BackColor="#34495E" Orientation="Vertical">
                         </asp:Menu>
                    </div>
```

My expectation is it should come like below -

[image]

What can I change in the code to achieve this? Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: We need all the code and data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: or use [third-party control](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxNavigationAndLayoutDemos/Menu/DataBinding.aspx) for this purpose